# How to track redirects accross domains in firebug/firefox?

Tags: firefox, redirection, firebug

I have Firebug, I'm on the net tab, persist is on, but when i enter "olddomain.com" and it redirects to "newdoamin.com", the "olddomain.com" request is removed from the console. I want all redirects across domains to persist, not just redirects within one domain. Can this be done? I need to see all of the headers that are involved.

If not, can I make Firebug break on redirect?

There's a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/242138/how-to-track-url-redirects-in-browser) but it didn't apply to cross domain redirects which don't seem to persist.

Comment: see new [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1173458/431840) in similar question you provide. You should just enable `persistent logs` so browser will not clear **Network tab** when redirecting to different site.